# Redefine Generics in the child component

Tags: typescript, formik

I have two formik forms. The bigger one contains the smaller one, which was componentized to be used in many other bigger forms.

I defined formik as follows in the bigger form:

```
const formik = useFormik<BiggerFormSpecificTypes & SmallerFormTypes>
```

Then I pass that to the child component like this:

```
<SmallerFormComponent formik={formik}/>
```

Ideally, I want `SmallerFormComponentProps` to contain `formik: FormikProps<SmallerFormTypes>`, but that obviously doesn't work because `formik` that I pass down is already defined to be `Formikprops<BiggerFormSpecificTypes & SmallerFormTypes>` in the parent component.

So I end up doing this in the child component, which I don't like:

```
const { values, handleChange, setFieldValue } = formik as FormikProps<SmallerFormTypes>;
```

How should I type `formik` in the child component?

```
interface SmallerFormComponentProps {
  formik: ???
}
```

I thought about using Partial, but that's to partially select from FormikProps, not to redefine FormikProps with SmallerFormTypes.

Comment: Why doesn't `FormikProps<BiggerFormSpecificTypes & SmallerFormTypes` work?

Comment: @caTS The smaller component is used by many bigger forms, so I'll end up defining it as `FormikProps<BiggerForm1SpecificTypes & SmallerFormTypes> | FormikProps<BiggerForm2SpecificTypes & SmallerFormTypes> | ...`

Comment: 6 lines of code isn't nearly enough to find a solution. It's hard to conceptualize what you have and what the problem is. Is the problem that you want to turn `FormikProps<BiggerFormTypes & SmallerFormTypes>` into `FormikProps<SmallerFormTypes>` in the child? "Narrow" or "reduce" the type given?

Comment: @caTS Yeah that's exactly it. And the problem is that `interface SmallerFormComponentProps { formik: FormikProps<SmallerFormTypes> }` does not work because the component receives formik with another type (i.e FormikProps<BiggerFormTypes & SmallerFormTypes>)

Answer (score 0):

Figured out that I can use the generics as follows:

```
export default SmallerFormComponent<T extends SmallerFormTypes>(props: SmallerFormComponentProps) { ... }
```